# Convert a Firestore Security Rules Set() to a String value(s)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

According to the Firestore security rules docs, using the [affectedKeys()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff#affectedKeys) MapDiff function will return a `rules.Set()`.

```
function getName() {
  return ({"alice":"owner", "john":"writer"}).diff({"john":"writer"}).affectedKeys();
}
```

In the example above, `["alice"]` would be returned from the function, but as a Set type, not a List type.

I am in need of casting the returned value as a String (`"alice"`) rather than a Set, but so far am unable to find a way to do that. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Based on the provided code, the returned set would actually be `["alice", "bob"]`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `getName()`? What rule are you trying to create with it?

Comment: In v2 of firestore's security rules, one is allowed to use `let` to assign a variable. I wish to assign a string value to the returned `getName()` key(s) and use it(them) for other data validation purposes.

Comment: That didn't quite answer the question I asked - Let's say you had some rule, that required the name "alice" - You could use `"alice" in getNames()` or `getNames().hasAny(["alice"])` because `name == "alice"` would be invalid in this context.

Comment: I plan to use the returned value to access a nested map sub-key elsewhere using `get()`. The returned value from `getName()` will always be a single key name, but I do not know what its value will be. Indeed, if I knew the value, I could test for it as you mention. The situation is not ideal, but it's the one I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be, if you could convert a Set to a List.  But without that conversion, it's not possible. I suggest filing a feature request with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Thank you, Doug. That's disappointing, but helpful. At least I now know I can stop looking for an existing solution.

Comment: I have filled up this request a few days ago... Will remove my duplicate question here

Comment: Seconding the request for Set to List. A good use case is a document summarizing all Storage uploads by a user (possibly by folder). If we allow them annotate that data, we need a way to prevent them from modifying things like the total size. So, the key is going to be unknown, but we still want to validate which subfields are being updated. There are workarounds, but they involve one of the following: more reads (when reading subcollections later), more writes (for a separate flag document), or more complicated listers (for a designated write key in the same document).

Comment: @ChrisChiasson File your request with Firebase support using the link in the answer.  They aren't looking very carefully at Stack Overflow as a source for demand.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes sir I was intending to, but there is a character limit on comments (so I didn't write I was going to do that in my original).